# How to save info to mysql from android app, via servlet

Tags: android, mysql, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to learn how to use a servlet to save some info from my android app to a mysql database. For example a simple registration form. I have no clue how to start, and the examples that i have found so far have been vague or not what i want.

I have apache tomcat 8.0.0-RC5 up and working and i have already created a table in mysql database. I found an example and did the webapp successfully, but i need to be able to do it on android.

Can someone please direct me to somewhere with clear and precise steps, or explain to me how im suppose to start.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions, I need something similar and I resolve in this way, in the application  (android) I serialize the info (form info) to json using gson, and make a post to the servlet in the servlet read the input stream or get the parameter depending how you send the info, deserialize the data using gson and saving this info in the database.

Other approach is to use some rest service, using for example Spring MVC, o Jersey you can exponse and rest endpoint the receive the data send from your application.

Comment: do you think you can send me an example code? because i searched and i still dont userstand. i am trying to use the option with gson. thanks.

Comment: please please please help? im rushing for my final year project that's due soon. i need help on the posting part. my understanding so far: get the form info and serialize it using gson,

Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(uname);
gson.toJson(pword);

after thata, i dont know how to add it to httppost so that i can "send" it over to the servlet.

Comment: Here there is a good tutorial check it out. http://www.veereshr.com/Android/AndroidToServlet